# Xdebug is running but not debugging on laragon

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, laragon

I have set up the Xdebug correctly and I can see it is running but does not debugging.
Also I have set up php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug_remote_autostart=1
;zend_extension=xdebug
zend_extension = "C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_host = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

[image]`enter code here`

Comment: 1) You have Xdebug v3 (`php_xdebug-3.0.4`) but Xdebug config uses Xdebug v2 parameters. They do almost nothing in v3 -- go through the upgrade guide first: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide 2) `xdebug.remote_host = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"` -- WHAT? This is wrong. Please check Xdebug doc on what `remote_host` (in v3 it's `client_host`) does and how it should be. This has to be an IP of the computer where your debug client (VSCode in your case) is running -- not your website address, not HTTP protocol included.

Comment: It was actually the configuration was wrong. I changes my configuration file.

Comment: {
  "configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
      "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
      "-S",
      "localhost:127.0.0.1:8000"
    ],
    "program": "",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "port": 9003,
    "serverReadyAction": {
      "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
      "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
      "action": "openExternally"
    }
  }
  ] 
}

Comment: [xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
zend_extension = "C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"

Comment: Yes -- you have switched to Xdebug v3 parameters now (original config is for v2). 