# Xdebug starts the connection and than closes automatically

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using Visual Studio Code and Xdebug is by default installed in it with version v3.x.x.

Sharing configuration below,

launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,   
            "stopOnEntry":true,        
            "log": true,
            "hostname": "localhost",     
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/app": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

php.ini,

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

test.php

```php
<?php
echo "<script>alert('Welcome');</script>";
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now when I start the debugger at port 9001 on my local host (note no remote hosting is there). And on accessing it via, `http://localhost:9001/test.php`

It gives following comments on Debug console,

new connection 1
new connection 2

It gets started, but for some strange reason gives me, two new connection and they are printed only after I have access it via browser.

Now I wait for 5-10 seconds (meanwhile, browser keep loading, but nothing is visible and its still attempting to access test.php) I have placed Debugger point on all lines.

And suddenly after 10 seconds, its closes connection with below comments,

```
<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: { category: 'console', output: 'connection 2 closed\n' }
}

connection 2 closed

<- continuedEvent
ContinuedEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'continued',
  body: { threadId: 2, allThreadsContinued: false }
}

<- threadEvent
ThreadEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'thread',
  body: { reason: 'exited', threadId: 2 }
}

<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: { category: 'stderr', output: 'connection closed\n' }
}

**connection closed**
```

I have checked everywhere, but unable to to find answer to my problem. Request for help

Comment: *"Now when I start the debugger at port 9001 on my local host (note no remote hosting is there). And on accessing it via, http://localhost:9001/test.php"* This is simply **wrong**. 1) Xdebug port is for Xdebug and debug client ONLY -- it should NOT be used as a web site address. 2) It's Xdebug that connects to debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. So right now you have `9001` port used by web server ... and VSCode is the one that also needs to listen on that port. No wonder that it closes as the prot is already in use by another app.

Comment: Xdebug v3 uses `9003` port by default. Since I see nothing about specifying custom port in php.ini, your VSCode `launch.json` should have `"port": 9003` (9003 instead of 9001). In any case: troubleshooting has to be done using Xdebug's own log -- enable that and try to debug and then see what it has to say. 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 2) https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your reply, As suggested by you i have updated port to 9003 in launch.json, but than when I try to run my application via terminal from VScode (php -S localhost:8877 -t public) , running localhost:8877/test.php doesn't stop at debugger points . I have placed debugger for all lines of code. It simply skips them and I dont see Xdebug catching anything

Comment: @LazyOne Diagnostic tools gives no message in error. My concern is how will Xdebug will know that he has to listen to localhost:8877 port for debugging the application. As per above messages what I have understood is that, Xdebug connect to VSCode for listening,  but how will Xdebug know that my application is running on port 8877. Looks like something is missing from my end, and hence its missing all debug points

Comment: So what's your xdebug log has? Anyway: check 1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/68668079/783119 2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/65316966/783119 . I'm not really using VSCode myself (I'm happy PhpStorm user) .. but just checked and I can easily debug CLI PHP scripts in VSCode -- https://i.imgur.com/bopBDGX.png and https://i.imgur.com/7sYTu4m.gif. For a web page I would have to do additional set up which I do not really want to do ATM...

Comment: @LazyOne Let me give it a try with PHPstorm as well, but what is the ideal configuration for php.ini for my application running on localhost:8877

Comment: @LazyOne One more question I have , where are you running your PHP application via XAMPP or from PHPStorm terminal for debugging using Xdebug

Comment: If you want to use PhpStorm: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html . Your Xdebug config -- first 2 lines of your php.ini -- that should be enough. Xdebug will use default `localhost` and `9003` as host/port to connect to. Xdebug will will show where it tries to connect (if it tries at all) and what the response is. I'm using IIS  (Windows web server) to serve my local dev websites. But can debug any PHP, even PHP own built-in server.

Comment: P.S. 1) It always makes sense to check your actual / live Xdebug config -- either using `phpinfo()` and checking Xdebug section.. or just `xdebug_info()` for that info only. 2) Use Xdebug log to see what is happening with Xdebug. 3) See if adding `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code (programmatic breakpoint) will make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to start Xdebug with Visual Studio code on XAMPP server. I am sharing my solution so that others don't face similar issues.

1. Install XAMPP on Ubuntu
2. Configure it to route it to code outside htdocs folder
   Follow this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/64095/change-xampps-htdocs-web-root-folder-to-another-one
3. Create index.php file and run,
   phpinfo();
4. open browser and execute localhost/index.php
5. Copy the text to https://xdebug.org/wizard
6. The resultant will be a page with list of instrcutions, just follow them one by one and make sure Xdebug is successfully installed on Ubuntu
7. Now the important piece, open file **/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini** (I was trying to configure my local Laravel php.ini in my code, that's where its failing to recognize)
   and paste following commands,

   xdebug.mode=debug

   xdebug.start_with_request=yes

   xdebug.client_port=9003

   xdebug.client_host = localhost

   zend_extension = "/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"
8. Now go Visual Studio Code and open apply debugger points on your index.php
9. If running and debugging is not yet configured (no launch.json has been created), VS Code will show that and you can configure it by Running. Leave launch.json settings default.
10. Go to Run --> Start Debugging -> "Listen for Xdebug" and configure same for PHP for first time.

That's it !